# Example data source for educaional use

Tags: statistics, training, self-study

I'm doing project on subject of affinity analysis for my statistical class in college.

In order to complete it, I have to acquire sales database with at least 200-300 records, each containing list of products bought by single client.

Are there any example sales databases available for free to use for such educational purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of the needed data is quite general, but I have found [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mehdidag/black-friday) that describes sales during Black Friday; it is possible to identify products bought by the same customer using customer_id column.

Also, [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/xvivancos/transactions-from-a-bakery) describes transactions from a bakery. The products that were bought in the same transaction (and so by the same customer) are identifiable as they share the same #Transaction value.

Generally below are 2 sources where someone can find free datasets that can be used for training/ educational purposes:

- Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets (both datasets that I suggested were found here)
- EU Open Data Portal: https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data

Comment: It seems like it is exactly what I need. Thank You very much for such fast reply!